# no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label ' ' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am using cucumber to test my rails application.

To fill a form, I am using "fill in" step in cucumber:

```
When /^(?:|I )fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/ do |field, value, selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    fill_in(field, :with => value)
  end
end
```

I have a page 
and I would like to fill in the "Email Address" with "example@example.com":

When I fill in "Email Address" with "example@example.com"

but I get the following error for one of the pages:

**no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Email Address' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)**

Any ideas that what is missing in the html code? or the problem is with the versions that do not match?

This is part of the html code for that page that I am getting the error for:

```
<p class=" medium text email_wrapper required">
 <label for="user_email">Email Address<span class="required">*</span></label> <br />
 <input class=" medium text" id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" /><br />
 <span class=" note">Must be valid. Privacy is guaranteed.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: This is part of the html code for that page that I am getting the error for: </div>
<p class=" medium text email_wrapper required"><label for="user_email">Email Address<span class="required">*</span></label> <br /> <input class=" medium text" id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" /><br /><span class=" note">Must be valid. Privacy is guaranteed.</span></p>

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your regexp is valid? Seems like it doesn't work. http://rubular.com/r/RUIKYIk5Wb

Answer (score 0):

This html in the label may be confusing the matcher:

```
<span class="required">*</span>
```

You can specify the field's id instead:

```
When I fill in "user_email" with "example@example.com"
```